# What need I do to get an HTML page to respect a French e (é)?

Tags: html, utf-8, character-encoding, char, non-ascii-characters

I have some HTML which renders like this:

"Les MisÃ©rables" Bilingual Edition: French and English Paragraph by Paragraph (Kindle only)"

...which makes it look like some kind of haywire "Les Misacrables"

This is the HTML:

```
<p><cite>"Les Misérables"</cite> Bilingual Edition: French and English Paragraph by Paragraph (Kindle only)</p>
```

What can I do to get the é to appear decently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is use the HTML code of the character rather than the character itself. In this case it would be the HTML code: `&eacute;` The result is: é

For other characters, you can look up their HTML code counterparts here: http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm

Comment: This is really not recommended since it offers no real fix!

Answer (score 3):

Check your Encoding.

Like:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
```

If the content of your page comes from a Database you want to check your **Database Encoding** as well.
It could also be **the Text Editor** that you use to create the pages that saves the file with a particular Encoding.

Check all of them depending on your situation.

Answer (score 2):

You need the utf-8 meta in your `<head></head>`

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html>
        <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        </head>
    <body>
Les Misérables
    </body>
    </html>
```

And remember to save your file with UTF-8 encoding.